# Multiplying pointers in assembly x86

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, addition, multiplication

I just started with assembly; sorry if this is a noob question.

So, I'm given i, from another function, which is a pointer to an int. I need to multiply 5 by this, but everything I've tried gives me errors.

```
lea (i), $ebp
lea (i), $ebx

addl %ebx, %ebx  #error: no such instruction: `add1 %ebp,%ebp'
add1 %ebx, %ebx 
addl %ebx, %ebp 

movl %ebp,(i)
```

so, I tried it another way. Couldn't get it to work. I kept changing syntax on the second lea, and probably made it worse.

```
lea (i),$ebp
lea $ebp, $ebp + $ebp * 4

movl %ebp,(i)
```

update: I made the correction Micheal suggested. Now I get "Error: suffix or operands invalid for `lea' "

Comment: `no such instruction: 'add1 %ebp,%ebp'` That because you wrote the digit `1` instead of the letter `l`.

Comment: Are you trying to load the effect address of the pointer (get a "pointer to pointer")? The code should mostly be a `mov` (to load the pointer from the stack into the EAX register) and then a single `lea (%eax,%eax,4), %eax` to multiply it by 5 (note: this is much clearer in Intel syntax - e.g. `lea eax,[eax*4+eax]`).

Comment: Multiplying pointers doesn't make sense. How is it that you multiply your home address by 5? A typical array access will have base address **plus** index*sizeof(type)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
movl (i), %eax
lea  %eax + 4 * %eax, %eax
movl %eax, (i)
```

Or the longer version:

```
movl (i), %eax
movl %eax, %ebx
addl %eax, %eax
addl %eax, %eax
addl %ebx, %eax
movl %eax, (i)
```

Your use of `lea` in the first line is wrong. "LEA" stands for "Load Effective Address", so it gives you an address, not a content. `i` is already an address, and

```
lea (i), %ebp
```

Would simply load `%ebp` with the *address* of the expression `(i)`, which is simply `i` again, not its contents. But you need the content, so use `movl`.

In other words:

```
lea (i), %eax
```

is equivalent to

```
movl i, %eax
```

and that is not what you want. You want the content of `i`, so you write:

```
movl (i), %eax
```

## Disclaimer

- I hope I got that (terrible, IMO) AT&T syntax right.
- The instructions used above are LEA, MOVL and ADDL, but apparently it is customary to write those in lower case.

Comment: Upvoted because of `terrible` at&t syntax. (what a mess).